# Is the Banach space of continuous functions on a compact space with a coutable base separable?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space with a countable base. Let $C(X)$ be the Banach space of complex valued continuous functions on $X$.

> Is $C(X)$ separable, i.e. does it have a countable dense subset?

The motivation is as follows(I think it is unnecessary to state it but some users tend to vote to close a question without it). Let $Y$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space with a countable base. Let $\mathcal B$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the family of all open subsets of $Y$. Let $\mu$ be a measure defined on $\mathcal B$ such that $\mu(K) \lt \infty$ for every compact set $K$. Let $p$ be a real number such that $1\le p \lt \infty$. Let $L^p$ be the Banach space of complex valued $p$-th integrable functions on $Y$ with respect to $\mu$. It is well-known that $L$ is dense in $L^p$ where $L$ is the set of complex valued continuous functions of compact support. I think the above question is related to the question whether $L^p$ is separable.

Comment: I expect that the answer is positive and the proof is similar to the [real case](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/118442/reference-for-x-compact-c-bx-separable-x-metric-space). Another way may be to consider a possible isomorphic embedding $i:C(X,\Bbb C)\to C(X,\Bbb R)^2$ by $i:f\mapsto (\operatorname{Re} f,  \operatorname{Im} f)$.

Comment: Indeed, as topological vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$, $C(X,\mathbb{C})$ is isomorphic to $C(X,\mathbb{R})^2$, so it follows from the real case. One can also directly prove the complex case in pretty much the same way as the real case.